# PostgreSQL database sync

Tags: database, postgresql

Im new to working with databases and Im trying to do the following

> Copy all databaseA schemas (which has several tables each and permissions attached) without any data to my
>   existing databaseB table as record fields (which now contains only one schema and
>   also a few tables and permissions attached)

databaseA is an Amazon redshift database & databaseB is an Amazon RDS database. Im connecting to both using DBeaver, databaseA I'm using a redshift driver & databaseB I'm using a PostgreSQL driver

After the inital copy I want to run a daily cron job that checks for the following

```
a. Compare databaseA to databaseB table 
   b. If databaseA does not match databaseB (in terms of schema & table permissions) 
      c. Then switch all perms to match databaseB table
```

Any feedback on how to approach this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a python script that connects to both of the databases. You could set up a cron job to spot the differences daily and to update the database.

You can have a query like this for PG:

`SELECT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name;`

And something like this for Redshift:

`SELECT schemaname, tablename 
FROM PG_TABLE_DEF;`

From there it`s just a matter of comparing the two and deciding if you want to update certain tables. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with AWS. Im translating the little knowledge I have from OCS which is a younger solution than AWS.
First, Amazon Redshift is tailored for Data warehousing. RDS is a cloud relational database. Im not sure what your aim is to copy from Redshift to RDS. It would be more natural to have the DB or multiple DB copy/clone to the data warehouse unless this was some form of backup. You might need to look into the architecture of your solution.
Oracle Cloud which is fairly new provides a service for copying. Amazon should have a similar solution as they have been in the cloud business longer.
I have had a look at the Amazon documentation. Your challenge has a solution "backwards" [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-copy-tables/). 
After copying the two dbs my assumption is they would be similar structurally. What is affecting the changes on dbA ? It feels like you don't want to use the permissions on dbA maybe its compromised. 
My suggestion is to use permissions to prevent changes to dbA. Look at the IAM documentation and check the logs for dbA. If you really need to develop a solution use the API or CLI to interface with the db